# Apple Mach-O Linker (id) Error when trying to build an Objective C project

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, linker-errors

I have been trying to work on an existing Objective C project provided by client and when i try to run the project i get this error. Could anyone help me how to fix this ?

[image]

Edit : I am actually sorry, i used a different image screenshot than what my actually problem is. I have replaced my image in the question now.

Comment: Oops sorry, I have had a linker error but i used a different screenshot that what my actual problem is. I have edited the question now could you please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I have met this question days ago, my problem was I forgot drag one of my using-frameworks into `Link Binary With Libraries`. maybe you should check this.
Also you should check if `ImageObjCommentTableViewCell` these classes which mentioned in the error log contained in the `Compile Sources`.